# No WiFi Icon on Mate

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, icons, mate, parrot-os

I was using my Linux machine and one day my WiFi icon disappeared, it was working along time ago so i had no idea why it was not working. I downloaded kde-plasma to use when i connected through wpa_supplicant when it also had no WiFi icon. I did some research and found out that kde-plasma has the package plasma-nm for the icon so i got that and to my surprise it showed up. I don't really like plasma that much though and still want to use Mate

I'm running:
Debian, Parrot Security OS v4.10

Answer (score 0):

Parrot, if I recall, uses the Maia icon set.

In this set, Network Manager icons are in /usr/share/icons/maia/apps/scalable, /devices/scalable and /status/scalable.

ls | grep nm-, network or Network in these folders to check their state.

You might also want to reset the icons:

sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/maia/

... Though I tended to find this throws an 'invalid' error for the maia set.